# ggplot2 basic theme is not theme_gray

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I used ggplot command to make basic scatter plot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=, y=)) + geom_point()
```

This gives me scatter plot, but background is white (in RStudio), this reminds me of `theme_bw`. So it does not look like default `theme_gray`.

If I put in `theme_gray`, it does not change. Other themes like `theme_dark` and `theme_economist` change plot, but `theme_gray` does not.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=, y=)) + geom_point() + theme_gray()
```

Have anyone any idea what is causing this? I have no error messages after running this. I would like to use gray background so plot would be easier to read.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps another package is loaded on top of ggplot, like cowplot? That  changes the default theme.

Comment: It is possible - can I check this somehow? I tried to install ggplot2 again, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `theme`, add code `+ theme(plot.background = element_rect("grey92"))`.

[image]

In `theme_gray`, the default `panel.background` fill colour `grey92` and `plot.background` fill colour `white`.